# Difference between real_escape_string and prepare()?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, security

`prepare()` seems a bit tedious and unnecessary for a majority of my code. If I send a string in a SQL command, why can't I just sanitize it with `real_escape_string`? What's the difference? That's what I've been doing all the time and it worked well against SQL injections... Thanks.

Comment: Well for one, `*_real_escape_string` methods are DB specific, whereas `PDO::prepare` is portable.

Comment: It works well against injections right up until _you forget to do it_ :)

Comment: It's tedious but not unnecessary. But I don't really see how it is significantly more tedious than escaping each variable using the appropriate `escape_string` method?

Comment: @Shahar Trust me, you'll forget it

Comment: @Shahar What about the other guy who will be working on your code at some point? Sometimes "best practice" isn't just for you, but making sure your app is developed well for the next person who takes over.

Comment: Why is typing a shorter function name more tedious?

Comment: @JohnConde That doesn't address `real_escape_string`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20767765/46675

Comment: @vascowhite A short function name `prepare()` combined with all the other nonsense in MySQLi's prepared statement API (compared to PDO's easier one) is kinda tedious

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Escaping is just as effective at SQL injection defense as using query parameters.

Both methods are also less effective if you fail to do them consistently.

Both methods are useful only for protecting individual *values* in SQL expressions. They don't support other dynamic parts of the query. For example, if you want to ORDER BY a user-specified column. Neither query parameters nor escaping functions handle that.

So basically, it is a matter of style and personal preference.

I prefer query parameters because I think this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO mytable (columna, columnb, columnc) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$a, $b, $c]);
```

Is more clear than this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO mytable (columna, columnb, columnc) VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $a)."', '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $b)."', '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $c)."')";
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

You can't seriously be saying that fiddling with all those open-quotes/close-quotes and `.` string concatenation is easier than using prepare() with query parameters.

---

Re your comments about a hypothetical `query()` function with parameters.

First of all, it's not necessary. Using prepare() and execute() together is a small price to pay for writing secure code, and by insisting on doing it with a single function, you just sound lazy. I suppose you don't check the return value of functions that return `false` on error, either?

For what it's worth, it'd be easy to write a wrapper function to do both, because PHP supports varargs implicitly.

```
function myquery() {
  global $pdo;
  $params = func_get_args();
  $sql = array_shift($params);
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute($params);
  return $stmt; // so we can fetch(), etc.
}
```

Comment: This says what I wanted to say but much better!

Comment: @Shahar, that usage is not supported by PDO::query(). Where did you see that?

Comment: @Shahar, there is no pdo_query() function. PDO is used only in an object-oriented calling style.

Comment: @Shahar it is "foolproof" in that it is completely made-up syntax and will never run no matter how many times you ask about it. That is not valid syntax for either PDO or mySQLi.

Comment: As for being foolproof, query parameters are *safe* when used consistently, just like escaping is. No API can protect against fools.